# Thread-safe sorted collection that supports iteration in Java

Tags: java, collections, thread-safety, iteration, jquery-ui-sortable

Is there a Collection in java that is :

1. Thread-Safe
2. Sorted
3. Iterable (or has an equivalent method of element access that is thread safe)

I can't seem to find any just by searching google/javadocs thanks for the help!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What about a [skip list](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentSkipListSet.html)?

Satisfies all your constraints:

- thread safety
- intrinsically sorted
- iterable

Comment: EXACTLY what i was looking for thank you, will accept as soon as i can :D

Answer (score 3):

Just to offer another possibility, you can use the `java.util.Collections` class to created a synchronized and sorted `Set` like so:

```
Set<String> myset = Collections.synchronizedSortedSet(new TreeSet<String>());
```

It wasn't specified in the question whether you wanted `List` or `Set` semantics, so I just thought I'd offer this up as an alternative.  Although I imagine the `ConcurrentSkipListSet` probably offers better performance because it seems to offer lock free behavior whereas the solution above is synchronized and thus locks.